# Merge 2 tabs into 1 on Customer Information page

Tags: tabs

How can I merge 2 tabs into 1 tab on this admin page:

```
Customers -> Manage Customers -> Click on a customer
```

The tabs I'm wanting to merge are "*Customer View*" and "*Account Information*".

It seems that the "*Customer View*" tab loads it's block and template through the `customer.xml` layout file.

And the "*Account Information*" tab seems to loads it's block in `Tabs.php` by calling `createBlock(..)->initForm()->toHtml()`.

I'm unsure how I can use both tab's html content on 1 tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function in Customer View tab that returns the html of Account Information tab, i.e. in **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View.php** add:

```
public function getAccountHtml()
{
    return $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_account')->initForm()->toHtml();
}
```

then call this function in **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml** at the bottom of the file:

```
<?php echo $this->getAccountHtml(); ?>
```

and finally hide Account Information tab if it's not a new customer - in **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tabs.php** replace this:

```
$this->addTab('account', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Account Information'),
    'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_account')->initForm()->toHtml(),
    'active'    => Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId() ? false : true
));
```

with this:

```
if (!Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId()) {
    $this->addTab('account', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Account Information'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_account')->initForm()->toHtml(),
        'active'    => Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId() ? false : true
    ));
}
```