# Move image upload field to a different tab

Tags: admin, adminhtml

How can I move the image upload field to the General tab (when adding a new product in the admin panel)?

I tried moving the image attribute into the General tab, but it didn't do anything. I also found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56048/merge-2-tabs-into-1-on-customer-information-page) but I'm unsure how to apply it for the images tab.